# QML/Qt3D Basic example of GeometryRenderer use

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qt3d

I'm looking for a basic example of how to set up an Entity with a GeometryRenderer in QML.

The code I'm using right now is shown below. If I replace `geometryRenderer` by a `CuboidMesh` then a blank cube is shown. The goal is to display a simple triangle. Is my GeometryRenderer declaration correct ?

```
Entity{

    Material{
      id: simpleMaterial 
      effect: SimpleEffect{}
    }

    GeometryRenderer{
      id: geometryRenderer

    instanceCount: 1
    primitiveType: GeometryRenderer.Triangles
    geometry: Geometry{

            Attribute{
                attributeType: Attribute.VertexAttribute
                vertexBaseType: Attribute.Float
                vertexSize: 3
                byteOffset: 0
                byteStride: 3 * 4
                count: 3

                buffer : Buffer{
                    id: vertexBuffer
                    type: Buffer.VertexBuffer
                    data: [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                            0.0, 10.0, 0.0,
                            10.0, 10.0, 0.0]
                }
            }
        }
    }

components: [simpleMaterial, geometryRenderer]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the following: the `data` property of the Buffer object actually expects a [QByteArray](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#resize). However, QByteArray is not a QML type and simply writing the vertices in a list won't do the trick.

The solution is to write a C++ wrapper which is then [made available to QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html). This wrapper should offer at least a readable property to a QBuffer or directly a QByteArray.

It is then possible to set the wrapper's data using either C++ or QML (provided some write function, [see here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html)).

The following code is a basic example, I adapted it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820903/billboarding-using-qt3d-2-0) where it is more complete in terms of functionality.

```
Entity{

    property DrawData drawData

    Material{
        id: material
        ...
    }

    GeometryRenderer{
        id: geometryRenderer

        instanceCount: drawData.count
        primitiveType: GeometryRenderer.TriangleStrip

        geometry: Geometry{

            Attribute{
                name: "vertexPosition" // Name of attribute in the shader
                attributeType: Attribute.VertexAttribute
                vertexBaseType: Attribute.Float
                vertexSize: 3
                byteOffset: 0 // See OpenGL doc for details about these properties
                byteStride: 3 * 4
                count: drawData.count
                buffer : drawData.buffer // The actual QBuffer which holds the vertex data
            }
        }
    }

    components: [material, geometryRenderer]
}
```

Where `DrawData` is defined as follows:

```
/* 
 * This struct is not strictly necessary, it is just convenient in case more
 * vertex attributes are needed. If so, it is necessary to change the ByteStride 
 * in the geometry attribute. 
 */ 
struct DrawVBOData {
QVector3D position;
};

class DrawData : public Qt3DCore::QNode {
    Q_OBJECT
    // Make properties available in QML
    Q_PROPERTY(Qt3DRender::QBuffer *buffer READ buffer CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(int count READ count NOTIFY countChanged)

public:
    explicit DrawData (Qt3DCore::QNode *parent = 0);
    Qt3DRender::QBuffer *buffer();
    void setData(const QVector<QVector3D> &positions);
    int count() const;

signals:
    void countChanged(int count);

public slots:

private:
    QScopedPointer<Qt3DRender::QBuffer> m_buffer;
    int m_count = 0;
};
```

And finally, the implementation:

```
DrawData::DrawData(Qt3DCore::QNode *parent)
    : Qt3DCore::QNode(parent), m_buffer(new QBuffer(QBuffer::VertexBuffer, this)){}

Qt3DRender::QBuffer *DrawData::buffer() { return m_buffer.data();}

void DrawData::setData(const QVector<QVector3D> &positions) {
    QByteArray ba;
    ba.resize(positions.size() * sizeof(DrawVBOData));
    DrawVBOData *vboData = reinterpret_cast<DrawVBOData *>(ba.data());
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++) {
        DrawVBOData &vbo = vboData[i];
        vbo.position = positions[i];
    }
    m_buffer->setData(ba);
    m_count = positions.count();
    emit countChanged(m_count);
}

int DrawData::count() const { return m_count; }
```