# Display an in-memory mesh in QML scene

Tags: c++, qml, qt3d

In my application I'm generating a 3D mesh from a medical dataset. Now I'd like to show it in a Qt App in QML. I already found how to show the mesh from files, but this requires me to save the mesh every time it modified (e.g. by changing the segmentation parameters)

```
Mesh {
    id: mesh
    source: "mesh.obj"
}
```

I'd like to show the mesh in a 3D viewer without having to save the mesh to a file first.

How can I do this in QML?

Answer (score 2):

Qt3D mainly wraps OpenGL which means that you can proceed to upload your mesh data to the graphics card in the known way using vertex/index array objects - but of course through Qt3D's classes and not the native OpenGL ones.

Have a look at [this code](https://github.com/GarageGames/Qt/blob/master/qt-5/qt3d/examples/qt3d/custom-mesh-cpp/main.cpp) of the Qt3D example where they create a triangle only in memory. You can translate all C++ instructions pretty easily into a QML tree. What you need to do is to transfer the vertex data that you already have to your attributes. Qt3D should then draw your mesh if you left the render policy on your `RenderSettings` at `Always`.

If you have your mesh data ist present in C++, an alternative is to write a custom C++ class that maps your data to the format like in the example and then make it available to QML.

**Edit**

Looks like there is an issue when trying to pass the vertex data directly to Qt3D in QML because it cannot be converted to `QByteArray`. But here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296979/qml-qt3d-basic-example-of-geometryrenderer-use) how to solve it with a custom C++ class.

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know